# Cannot locate mysterious crunching/grinding noise

Tags: repair

I've seen other posts on this general subject.

My BB seems tight, new chain installed by bike shop, gears all checked ... I am second owner of this Raleigh so no knowledge of past usage or maintenance ... could it be BB bearings?  Cannot detect what or where noise comes from ... any ideas?

Comment: When does it happen?

Comment: This is pretty vague. Without more details, theres pretty much no way to figure out what the noise is.

Comment: Based on your description, it could literally be coming from any part of the bike. You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: Are you eating biscuits?  Disassemble, clean and regrease the BB if that's what you think it is

Comment: "Grinding/chrunching"? Check the parts that have bearings: hubs, rear derailleur, and, especially if it happens only when pedalling, the pedals and the bottom bracket. If the noise is there even when not pedalling, it's likely one of the hubs – turn the bike upside down, turn the crank with the hand and look down on the rear wheel and cogs to check if there is anything 'wobbling'.  (Obviously, thats if you are sure it's not a tyre chafing a mudguard.)

Comment: A "crunching, grinding noise" generally means bad bearings.  You should be able to determine which bearing is doing it.  Disassemble that bearing and see what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the question is kind of vague (as others have pointed out) and it would help if you could say more about the (apparent) source and timing of the noises, but I just wanted to add a couple of thoughts:

1. I chased what I thought was a bottom bracket / crank arm clunk for quite a while before I noticed that my saddle wasn't clamped well. I'd moved it back as far as it could go (or actually a bit farther) and the seatpost wasn't able to get a solid grip on anymore due to the bend of the seat rails. I would still swear that the sound was coming from the bottom bracket…
2. My cleats are noisy. I figured this out one day when I rode with shoes without cleats. The noise seems to be specific to the particular shoes / pedals combination. Don't have any noise with the same shoes on a different bike with the same make/model of pedal.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a tiny amount of movement between the cassette and the freehub.  Try putting some grease on the freehub splines, and (more importantly) make sure the cassette lockring is tightened to the correct torque.

Check if the noise occurs on all cogs of the cassette, or just on a few cogs.  I had a case where there was a crunching noise only on the 3 largest cogs, which were joined into a single unit.